# Unit test laravel 4 controller passing JSON payload

Tags: laravel, phpunit, laravel-4

app/controllers/SecurityController.php

```
class SecurityController extends Controller { 

    public function login()
    {       
        $payload = file_get_contents("php://input");
        $payload = json_decode($payload);

        $input = array('mail' => $payload->mail, 
                       'password' => $payload->password,
                 );


        if (Auth::attempt($input))
        {
        }
     }
}
```

app/tests/SecurityTest.php

```
class SecurityTest extends TestCase {
    public function testLogin()
    {
        $data = array(
            'mail' => 'test@test.com',
            'password' => 'mypasswprd',
        );

        $crawler = $this->client->request('POST', '/v2/login', $data);
    }
```

When I run phpunit I'm getting this error:
.{"error":{"type":"ErrorException","message":"Trying to get property of non-object","file":app/controllers/SecurityController.php","line":20}}

Comment: Have you made any effort to debug up to now? What did you try?

Comment: The controller is receiving an empty payload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using `file_get_contents("php://input")` ? Laravel allow you to use the `Input:get()` method wich is an easy way to retrieve input data from form or json. I bet it will be more testable.

Your controller should be like that :

```
class SecurityController extends Controller { 

    public function login()
    {       
        $input = array(
            'mail'     => Input::get('mail'), 
            'password' => Input::get('password'),
        );

        if (Auth::attempt($input))
        {
        }
    }
}
```